# svg image not showing on react.js

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have been following a YouTube tutorial for making a website using react.js.

**index.js**:

```
import { Img, ImgWrap } from './InfoElements';

const InfoSection = ({ img, alt)} => {
     return(
            <>
              <ImgWrap>
                 <Img src={img} alt={alt}/>
               </ImgWrap>
            </>
           )
}
export default InfoSection
```

I have been exporting image src from another folder named Data.js

**Data.js**:

```
export const homeObjOne = {
   img: require("../../images/svg-1.svg"),
   alt: 'error404'
}
```

I used styled-components for style

**InfoElements.js**:

```
export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
    max-width: 555px;
    height: 100%;
`;

export const Img = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding-right: 0;
`;
```

Here image is placed on

src->images->svg-1.svg

I tried using other images like jpe, jpg and png rather than svg but still its not working. The image is not showing on background.

Here is the **picture the way image return**:

[image]

Here is the **path of image folder**:

[image]

I have been tried all other image format and result is same..Is their anything I done wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your structure is falling victim to a default export naming issue. When you require your image in Data.js, you're setting it as a module. If you want to access the URL of the image, you need to use:

```
export const homeObjOne = {
   img: require("../../images/svg-1.svg").default, //note the default part at the end
   alt: 'error404'
}
```

Although this could be made cleaner using imports:

```
import homeObjOne from "../../images/svg-1.svg";

export const homeObjOne = {
   img: homeObjOne, //no need for default here, thanks to import
   alt: 'error404'
}
```

Note: If you inspect your image whilst it is broken, you'll see the src will be `[object Object]`.

Comment: While adding default it worked.. the second method is also useful but i dont want to use like that.  Because I need to  use some more images.. Thanks for solving this issue

Answer (score 2):

Follow this article https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/unable-to-find-images-based-on-url-in-react/.

Move images folder under `/public` not `/src`.

In **data.js**

`img: "./images/svg-1.svg"`

Or use you can use `import`, like this `import image1 from "./images/1.jpg`